# How to call a similarly named function in LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have two classes defined "Table" and "Columns". I am trying to generate an XML with hierarchy Table>Column. I have written the following code for the same. This is function inside the Table class.

```
Public Function GetXmlTree() As XElement
    Dim ColumnNode As XElement = _
        <Table>
            <Name><%= ObjTable.Name %></Name>
            <Columns>
                <%= From col As SqlColumn In Columns _
                    Select col.GetXmlTree() %>
            </Columns>
        </Table>
    Return ColumnNode
End Function
```

This code give me the following error when I call the function GetXmlTree present inside the Column class, that is this part **col.GetXmlTree()**. Why is it treating the function like a variable.

The col.GetXmlTree() function also returns an XmlElement.

> **Error:**
>   Range variable 'GetXmlTree' hides a variable in an enclosing block or
>   a range variable previously defined in the query expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the full code, it's hard to test, but try specifying a name in the `Select` clause:

```
Public Function GetXmlTree() As XElement
    Dim ColumnNode As XElement = _
        <Table>
            <Name><%= ObjTable.Name %></Name>
            <Columns>
                <%= From col As SqlColumn In Columns _
                    Select x = col.GetXmlTree() %>
            </Columns>
        </Table>
    Return ColumnNode
End Function
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I am new to LINQ and had googled whole weekend for this but could not find a solution. For time being I had done this "Selelct CType(col.GetXmlTree(), XElement)". But yours is the correct solution.